# iOS auto layout and rearrange views on screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I try to arrange UIView on screen with AutoLayout. 
I get a list of views with starting points, width and height. Then I need to create constraints that represents similar arrangement with constraints, but all views need to be "snapped" to each other. They need to "fill" all white space.

For example : 
If I have views with coordinates :

```
View 1 : (0,0,300,200)
View 2 : (400,10,300,150)
View 3 : (10,300,200,200)
View 4 : (250,300,400,200)
View 5 : (5,600,400,200) 
View 6 : (506,600,200,200)
```

I would like to get something like that :

[image]

NOTE : It really need to use constraints and auto layout.

Is there a simple way to do that and I miss it?

Marko

Comment: You could add the width constraints as a minimum (ie, the width is greater than or equal to 200), and then constrain the edges of each view to touch each other

Answer (score 0):

The expected result is not really clear as you are defining your desired layout on points/pixels, and you should do it in percentage / relative.

Anyway you can do something like that :

```
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view1]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view1(>=200)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view1(==400)][view2]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view2(>=150)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view1(==view2)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view3]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view1][view3(>=200)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view3(==250)][view4]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view2][view4(>=200)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view3(==view4)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view5]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view3][view5(>=200)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view6.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[view5(==506)][view6]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view4][view6(>=200)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view5(==view6)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views))
```

If you are targeting iOS 9.x+ you can also you Stack views + constraints ; It will save you some coding lines.

Comment: Maybe I was not that clear in my question, but I need algoritem for any list of views, not for this exact. This was only for example...

Comment: Just adapt what I did in a loop. As I stated out you may need to  first calculate the max width and max height so you make all the positions and values relative.

Comment: No your code can't be called in for loop because you don't know witch view is on your left, right, top and bottom,... as you used in visual format of your constraints

Comment: Just put them in an array and sort them by x, y :-)

Comment: It is not that simple :D your suggestion would maybe working with predefined layout (specific number of "line" of views, specific number of view in line...), but if you get array of views with unpredicted starting points  and width and hight, your solution wouldn't work.